# Spring Data(Hibernate) в Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Здравствуйте, возник вопрос по поводу использования Spring Data(Hibrante) в Java. вопрос заключается в следующем: можно ли при мэппинге какого, либо объекта добавить дополнительную информация из БД в поле этого объекта, к примеру:

#### Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name= "increment", strategy= "increment")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    //Есть таблица Users в БД, и у них связь один ко многим. Хотелось
    //бы при мэппинге этого объекта посчитать кол-во пользователей в этой группе
    private int countUsers;

    public Group(){

    }

    public Group(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    //Seters, getters, equals and hash code

}
```

#### Repository

```
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Group, Long> {

    @Transactional
    void deleteByName(String name);

    @Transactional
    Group findByName(String name);

}
```

#### Service

```
@Service
public class GroupsServiceImpl implements GroupsService {

    @Autowired
    private GroupRepository groupRepository;

    public List<Group> getGroups() {
        return groupRepository.findAll();
    }

    public boolean addGroup(String nameGroup) {
        Group group = groupRepository.findByName(nameGroup);
        if(group == null) {
            groupRepository.saveAndFlush(new Group(nameGroup));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean changeNameGroup(String oldName, String newName) {
        Group oldGroup = groupRepository.findByName(oldName);
        Group newGroup = groupRepository.findByName(newName);
        if(oldGroup != null && newGroup == null){
            oldGroup.setName(newName);
            groupRepository.save(oldGroup);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean removeGroup(String nameGroup) {
        Group group = groupRepository.findByName(nameGroup);
        if(group != null) {
            groupRepository.deleteByName(nameGroup);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

На подобии этого существуют такие же классы и для Users. Можеть кто-нибудь подскажет как это возможно осуществить...

Answer (score 1):

Вижу 2 варианта:

В UserRepository определить метод:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(user) FROM Users user WHERE user.groupId=:groupId")
public int countUserInGroup(int groupId);
```

В классе Group описать это отношение и написать метод:

```
Set<User> users;

public int getCountUsers(){
   return users.size();
}
```

Comment: Допустим, если применить второй вариант, то при использовании такой зависимости, будет очень большая затрата с памятью, ведь придется брать всего пользователя со всеми полями, а мне бы хотелось бы только int. А первый вариант, это получается придется вызывать этот метод в конструкторе Group при создании, я правильно понимаю? Вообще на ваш взгляд что лучше будет?

Comment: Если User сущность тяжелая, то наверно лучше первый вариант. Попробуйте оба, включите отображение запросов и посмотрите что и как работает.

Comment: Но чтобы к примеру внедрить метод репозиторий в entity приедтся и Entity пометить компонентом, так вобще делают? Просто проверил, что второй вариант реально тяжелый.

Comment: нет просто добавьте метод в репозиторий (возможно придется подправить запрос, я его не тестировал, но вроде правильно написал)

Comment: Дуло как раз-таки в том, что мне нужно чтобы это было поля класса, в JSTL же на сколько я знаю можно будет только поле класса вызвать